# To integrate ant-design with next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd, next.js

I am trying to integrate `ant-design` with `next.js`. I have installed `next` in a default node project instead of using `create-next-app`.

I have followed [zeit example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design) of integrating `next` with `antd`.

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "crowd-funding",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "author": "Thananjaya Chakravarthy S",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^3.13.6",
    "next": "^4.1.4",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

And my `.babelrc` file is

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [
      ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
    ],
}
```

But I am getting an error like `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`, pointing towards the path `/node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css`.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

Create styles.css file

in styles.css:

```css
@import "~antd/dist/antd.css";
```

in _app.js:

```js
import "./styles.css";
```

now you can use ant design components anywhere in the project

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, while this may answer the question, it is better to give explanations and not only code for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a way to load css files, usually it comes to use [`css-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) but next has a shortcut calls [`next-css`](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css).

Just add to your `next.config.js` file this:

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

Checkout the official example: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-next-css/next.config.js

Comment: Could you update this answer after Nextjs 9.2 that supports css imports?